# combine multiple filter options, R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I want to extract certain rows based on 3-4 condition in each row from a large table
I do this in "dplyr"

```
gene1_fixed = gene1 %>% filter(V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'BEL-39_Dmon' & V20 == "ATP8B" & V19 == "106" | V19 == "107") %>%
                                   filter(V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'Gypsy-102_Dmon' & V20 == "Abl" & V19 == "74" | V19 == "169") %>%
                                   filter(V4 == "upstream" & V16 == 'Gypsy-181_Dmon' & V20 == "CG17571") %>%
                                   filter(V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'Gypsy-22_Dmon' & V20 == "CG1632")
```

this gives me an empty file, while each filter command works separately and returns the result, how can I combine properly these commands?

Comment: what do you want each line to do?  Your first filter only accepts `V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'BEL-39_Dmon'` while your second requires `V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'Gypsy-102_Dmon'` - there is no combination that satisfies both requirements so all rows are removed.    Can you explain in words what you need, and we can help with the syntax?

Comment: Do you want to select data that matched any of the criteria? If so then the operator for OR (|) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @PaulStaffordAllen , I want to extract all the rows the fits the conditions of all four filter commands, I understood %>% is not a good option because as you said it will only extract the first "BEL-39_Dmon" and then there is no more data to extract, so I tried to use && or || instead which also didn't work. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Nathan, I tried & and | and it doesn't recognize the functions, the error is `Error in filter(V4 == "intron" & V16 == "Gypsy-102_Dmon" & V20 == "Abl" &  : 
  object 'V4' not found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
gene1_fixed = gene1 %>%
  filter(
    (V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'BEL-39_Dmon' & V20 == "ATP8B" & V19 %in% c("106", "107")) |
    (V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'Gypsy-102_Dmon' & V20 == "Abl" & V19 %in% c("74", "169")) |
    (V4 == "upstream" & V16 == 'Gypsy-181_Dmon' & V20 == "CG17571") |
    (V4 == "intron" & V16 == 'Gypsy-22_Dmon' & V20 == "CG1632") |
  )
```